# Cannot recieve translation result with GoogleTranslateFreeApi

Tags: c#, api, xamarin

In my android app with c# xamarin I used `GoogleFreeTranslateApi` to translate a word- but for some reason it can not return a translate result value. When I press the translate button it waits and waits until it says - the android app isn't responding. There isn't some kind of error to show me what I'm doing wrong.
That`s the code im using

```
    private async void OnTranslateButtonReleased(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GoogleTranslator translator = new GoogleTranslator();
        var result = await translator.TranslateAsync("ball", Language.English, Language.Bulgarian);
        await DisplayAlert("Alert", result.MergedTranslation, "ok");
    }
```

And the other important thing is that in c# console app it works without any problems. like i wait 1 second and it returns the translated value.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using GoogleTranslateFreeApi;


namespace ARIWE
{
    class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            GoogleTranslator translator = new GoogleTranslator();
            var result = await translator.TranslateLiteAsync("ball",Language.English, Language.Bulgarian);
            Console.WriteLine(result.MergedTranslation);
        }

    }
}
```

Im new at programming and i cant figure it out why this is happening.

Comment: please do NOT post code or errors as images

Answer (score -1):

You need to use async await in the function to stop it from blocking the UI thread

Comment: when i use await instead of GetAwaiter().GetResult()- it throw`s me: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: 'Response status code does not indicate success: 429 (Too Many Requests).'- excpetion that has no description about the problem... i cant understant what im doing wrong

Comment: it sounds like Google is telling you that you are making too many requests - I can't say for sure because you did not post any code, just unreadable images

Comment: sorry i fixed it...im new at questioning :D